# Read Cells from Google Sheets in JavaScript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I would like to be able to read the values in a column from Google Sheet with JavaScript of HTML and add the values to a ComboBox or use them for other purpose.
Basically I want to imitate the following action in VBA with Excel. (In excel if I want to read the Values in Column A I would do something like)

```
Dim i as integer
Dim value as string
i = 1
//Read value on cell A1
Value = Range(“A” & i).value
//Keep reading values on column A till cell is empty
While value <> ” ” 
  Value = Range(“A” & i).value
 //Add the value to ComboBox
  With ComboBox1
    .AddItem value
  End With
//Increase value of row to look at
 i = i + 1
Do
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As of now Google doesn't seems to provide JS only API for Google sheets. You need to build a JAVA or ASP.NET server to read the Google Sheets and then have your JS code call REST APIs from that server to fetch data.
Check https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en